# Problem of distorsion using the displace modifier with an external displacement map

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement

Here my mesh, a simple tunnel with 2 modifiers :

1)  Subdivision surface

2)  Displace Modifier

[image]

In particular the displace modifier is created with the default library of Blender, ***Clouds*** like the image above shows.

Now i have imported this **seamless map** below and i want to use it instead of ***Clouds***. There it is:

[image]

This is my workflow:

1) I upgrade my definition with sub. surf. modifier, getting almost 200k vertices (this new displacement map need a mesh with more resolution in order to have a decent result).

[image]

2) I apply the sub modifier.

3) I select all my mesh in Edit Mode and I used Smart Uv Project for having a Uv Map with these stats below.

[image]

4) I open the displace modifier and insert the new displacement map. Here the stats I used:

[image]

[image]

The final results is pretty decent but there is a problem: there are 3 seams, that I underlined in red.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem causing this distorsion? I tryed with many **seamless texture** and there are always these three lines.

**Is there a method to fix it?**

Here's the file, just in case

[image]

Thank you!!

**EDIT: the problem could be created from seams of smart uv project. I tried with the unwrap and the results is this:**

[image]

[image]

**There is a way to fix it?**

Comment: One small note is that unless you really have to, don't apply the subsurf. There isn't any advantage to apply it (in this case).

Comment: I apply the subsurf cause i need the uv map of my high poly mesh, otherwise how can i create the uvmap? From the initial mesh? Does still work with the displace?

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't work just on the initial mesh.

Comment: Yes it's better; thank you @RayMairlot so much! I have just tried. Any advice about that lines; for sure are the seams of smart project view. i have already tried with the unwrap and where are the seams, there the lines. I edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make one seam along the whole tube (not around). Simply unwrap it. You should get a square. If it matches the whole UV space it will be seamless.

Comment: The problem is that I have not a cylinder but polygon with 9 sides, one of them flat. If i use this method my uv map overlaps and has many distorsion; Are there any different path?

Comment: @Fuboski I have changed my answer. It is a little short since I am at work. If you want more details I can give them later.

Comment: Yeah that pretty works!! Thank you so much @Gunslinger !! I would like to ask you this last thingh . . . If the target is to create a uv map that matches the whole uv space in order to be seamless (that means the uv map must become a square), It will be possible in Blender, whatever will be my uvmap after the unwrap, modify and adapt it like a square? Is there any addons or technique?